# Data comes from database correctly showing in the network tab, but when console logs it is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from the backend. The problem is only with the date(createdTs).The api is fetch rest of the data but not the `createdTS`. When I inspect and see the network tab there also I can see `createdTs` .But when I console log it in the service file that data logs as null.Is there a way to solve this?

**Database**
[image]

**Preview in the network tab**
[image]

**Services.js**

```
async findTicketByID(ticketId) {
    let comments = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/${ticketId}/comments`);
    let tickets = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/${ticketId}`);
    console.log(comments);
    return {
      comments: comments,
      tickets: tickets
    };
  },
```

**log result**
[image]

Comment: Are those from the same call? The `id` properties are different.

Comment: yes,There are many Ids' like ticket,employer etc. But this regards to comment id.Those two are same

Comment: Ah, I see. So if you click and expand the `comments` property in the first image (in the network tab?) does `createdTs` match or is there a discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Expand your console you can see all the data.

If you are facing issue while accessing data
Try this :
`console.log(comments[0]);`.
It may in array format